# Restful URI with multiple parameters for GET verb

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, restful-url

I want to call a restful API with GET verb to get response back from a SaaS service. The API exposes multiple objects to construct the request uri. How to construct the uri with proper value to pass? I am using .Net 4.5 client and c# to call this API.

Here is expected request URI template
GET v1/Times/{SiteId}/{OrderMode}/{OrderSource}/{MenuId}

I need to pass above uri template with proper value like SiteId=1, OrderMode=P, OrderStatus=1 and MenuId=1

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a string and convert to URI fairly easily, something like this:

```
const string getUriFormatter = "v1/Times/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}";

uri ConstructGetUri(int siteId, char orderMode, int orderStatus, int menuId)
{
    return new Uri(string.Format(getUriFormatter, siteId, orderMode, orderStatus, menuId), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, this is same with V1/Times/1/P/1/1 where  SiteId=1, OrderMode=P, OrderStatus=1 and MenuId=1. I tried with this and API giving error like path not found. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong anywhere.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying you have a completed URI, containing the values you believe to be correct, and the API is returning a 404 response?  If that's the case you either have the wrong URI, or there are no times available for that specific combination of values.  A 404 is the correct HTTP response in the latter case.  Doesn't this API have a way to fetch existing values for those params?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let me contact the service owner about this 404 error if it's one of the cases as you mentioned. Thanks once again.